# How to change UITableViewCell's height dynamically using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

**A self-sizing UITableViewCell**: *MyTableViewCell.m*

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
        UIView *sample = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [self.contentView addSubview: sample];

        //Fake code here. Let sample view fill the whole contentView:
        Constraint1: sample.leading = contentView.leading;
        Constraint2: sample.trailing = contentView.trailing;
        Constraint3: sample.top = contentView.top;
        Constraint4: sample.bottom = contentView.bottom;
        Constraint5: sample.height = 20;
        NSLayoutConstraint:activateConstriant(constraints 1-5);
}
```

This code works and the `MyTableViewCell` has a height of 20.

**However, I want to change the height at run time (after this cell added to a UITableView), so I add a new method** to *MyTableViewCell.m*

```
-(void) updateHeight:(CGFloat)newHeight{
        //Fake code here. change the constant of constraint1 
        Constraint1 = get reference of Constraint1 in viewDidLoad();
        Constraint1.constant = newHeight
}
```

I run the code and call `updateHeight:10` and got the log warning:

> 2017-03-16 16:23:11.102858 [14541:568021] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>       Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
>       Try this: 
>           (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
>           (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
>       (
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           ""
>       )
>       Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

My own opinion is that my constraints created at `viewDidLoad` automatically creates couple of other constraints like `contentView.height=20` and my change to the original constraints conflict with the constraints created by system.

I tested to change the leading of sample view instead of the height in `updateHeight:`, and it works! Because the change of leading doesn't affect contentView's own height constraint?

How am I supposed to do a dynamically change to auto layout like this case?

Thank you~~~

Comment: Try `sample.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO`. More often than not, this solves the problem.

Comment: Did you find out eventually? All answers here are for initialisation, not updating it on the go which is what you (and I) need. Any findings?

Answer (score 2):

To have dynamic cell size you need to implement the below methods

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return <your estimated cell height>;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: I've already make this a self-sizing cell. My problem is to change the height at run time, but thanks anyway

Comment: @LuRui can be explain on what exactly is the problem ? Are broken constraints your concern ?

Answer (score 1):

Set the tableview row height in your view controller. Refer the following code line :

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: I've already make this a self-sizing cell. My problem is to change the height at run time, but thanks anyway~.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `updateHeight:` method executed before cell's `layoutSubviews`. Because if cells has been loaded, you have to reload the tableView to make your new constraints effective, so you can figure out your automatic constraints in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, or the following code is what you need.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
// your code, alter your cell's constraints here
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 //put as per your cell row  height
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

- Give Top,Bottom,Leading,Trailing Contraints to **UILabel** used.
- Be sure numberOfLine for your **UILabel** in the cell is set to 0.
- Estimated row height needs to be provided.(Provide any appropriate value)

Comment: I've already make this a self-sizing cell. My problem is to change the height at run time, but thanks anyway

Comment: @LuRui what u want exactly ??if u want to run time give data to cell  and after  self.tableView.reloadData() will manage all height automatically .may it will help

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today and solved it by overriding the UITableViewCell object's drawRect method.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    [self adjustConstraint];
}
```